# Finding webcam specifications using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-multiprocessing

I am accessing the webcam using `multiprocessing` module whose GUI has been rendered by `Tkinter`.

With reference to the [Multiprocessing with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073227/display-an-opencv-video-in-tkinter-using-multiprocessing), is there a way to get the webcam's specifications like *resolution*, *exposure time*, using this module?

Comment: That depends: the GUI is calling commands from a communication library written to interact with the camera (e.g. a dll). That most likely has the commands you need to poll the camera about all of its settings. What is the name of the GUI application you're using (consider adding the website too).

Comment: I am using Tkinter . Have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that. But Tkinter is just the GUI layer. In the module it will be using a library that accesses the camera. What is the name of that module?

Comment: That's an Open CV module named VideoCapture() . I guess I got an answer to my question as Open CV has options of accessing and changing the Webcam parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the link [Display an OpenCV video in tkinter using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073227/display-an-opencv-video-in-tkinter-using-multiprocessing) the Process Function:

```
 p = Process(target=image_capture, args=(queue,))
```

transfers the command to function `image_capture`, which makes an instance of `VideoCapture` named `vidFile`. This instance can be used to find the camera specifications. Use:

```
print "Exposure Time " + str(cap.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE))
cap.set(15, -5) 
# 15 is used for Exposure time 
# and second parameter is the value 
# to which you are setting the exposure time
```

Refer to [setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python) for setting other parameters.