# Real-time video from numpy array, Python3

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, tkinter, scipy

I have an real-time input of array, like below:

```
275 242 280 263 235 179 234 236 233 195 203 190 202...
```

Approximately once a 10 ms.
Every array is pixel's value of image.
I want to make video stream from this data.
How is it possible?
Linux, python 3.4

I found some ways, but I'm not sure:

1) tkinter
2) matplotlib
3) opencv
4) scipy

Many thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image

Comment: What does "I want to make video stream from this data" mean? The data already seems to be a stream. Do you want to save it? (if so, in what format?) Do you want to display it (if so, where? In a brwoser, in a dedicated window etc?) Mind that Stackoverflow is a programming website, so you need to be more specific in your question and not ask questions like "What is the best way to achieve ___?"

Comment: Of course, sorry.
I want to make some "window" via Tk (e.g).
Which will be update each time after receiving data

Comment: There is e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/05/30/displaying-a-video-feed-with-opencv-and-tkinter/) about Tkinter and openCV and also [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073227/display-an-opencv-video-in-tkinter-using-multiprocessing) on SO. If you already have the array, you can ignore the CV part and directly put the image to the `tk.Label`. Matplotlib may actually be too slow for 10 ms updates. Again: Mind my comment above and also the one from CGritton.