# Is there a way of displaying a 16-bit image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library, opencv

I got a single-layer uint16 tiff image, i.e 2d array each value ranges between 0-65355.
When I read and display the image with cv2 it works corrrectly.

```
im = cv2.imread(path, -1)
cv2.imshow('im', im)
```

Now I'm trying to make a GUI with Tkinter and incorporate the image into the GUI, but all it displayed is a white canvas.

```
im = cv2.imread(path, -1)
height = im.shape[0]
width = im.shape[1]
canvas.config(width=width, height=height)
image = Image.fromarray(im)
root.photo = photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tk.NW)
```

Other types of RGB 8bit images are displyed as shuold.
How can I disply the image? what Im doing wrong?

Comment: See [`PIL.Image.fromarray(obj, mode=None)` Modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)

Comment: setting the mode to I;16 which is uint16 doesn't do anything

Comment: Relevant [`cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362559/7414759)

Comment: its a single channel image, there is no RGB, only intensity

Comment: Read about [tkinter Bitmapimage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue as of late without a solution. This is what I believe is causing the issue.

Your image [`mode`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) is type `I;16L`, but when you call [`ImageTk.PhotoImage‍`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageTk.html#PhotoImage) the constructor checks if the type is among the types `["1", "L", "RGB", "RGBA"]`. Since it is not, it gets the base mode of your type (in my case it was 'L') and converts to that base in the `paste` function of the PhotoImage class.

I do not know how to stop/bypass this conversion, so what I plan to do is show approximate versions of the images. I will take my images and convert to a standard 8-bit RGB then show that in the Tkinter GUI, but any manipulations will be made to the original images.

Edit: **My Work Around/Solution**

Because my image is type `I;32L`, I used OpenCV to open my image and NumPy to convert it to the appropriate type. Here's my example:

```
my_image = cv2.imread("image.tiff") # read in the image with OpenCV
my_image = np.uint8(my_image) # convert image into an unsigned 8 bit int array with NumPy
my_image = Image.fromarray(my_image) # read in image from array with Tkinter
rendered_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image) # create the photo image for display
```