# OpenCV Face Recognition Program Crashing

Tags: python, opencv, crash, tk-toolkit

Here's the code (I deleted everything that wasn't important)

```
closed = False

faceClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face.xml')
eyeClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('eye.xml')
bodyClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('body.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def drawBox():
    while closed == False:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceClassifier.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            eyes = eyeClassifier.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)

def stopProgram():
    closed = True

tkWindow = Tk()  
tkWindow.geometry('800x800')  
tkWindow.title('Machine Learning Face Detection')



button = Button(tkWindow,
text = 'Stop Program',
command = stopProgram)  
button.pack()  

button = Button(tkWindow,
text = 'Start Program',
command = drawBox)  
button.pack() 

tkWindow.mainloop()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As soon as I hit the start program error, the camera window opens gray and then it crashes. Anyone have any idea why? I can't figure it out, but it was working before I tried to implement the stop button.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you didn't mark `closed` as a global variable in your functions `drawBox` and `stopProgram`. Other problem is the while loop in `drawBox`, which will cause the program to stop responding, rendering "Stop Program" button unusable. You need to use `tkWindow.after`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362559/2962048)'s an example of displaying video frames from `cv2.VideoCapture` in `tkWindow`.