# python opencv QR scan in tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, opencv

I am trying to create a qr scanner using tkinter and opencv. On pressing QR scan button camara is opened in new frame and giving perfact results. What I want is when button is pressed camara should be opened in same tkinter window and not in new frame

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("SCANNER")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.config(background='black')
window.maxsize(500,500)


def scan():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()

        decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
        for obj in decodedObjects:
            # print("Data", obj.data)
            scanned.config(text=obj.data)
            cv2.putText(frame, str(obj.data), (50, 50), font, 2,
                        (255, 0, 0), 3)


        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)


        if cv2.getWindowProperty('Frame',cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE)<1:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

but3 = tk.Button(window,text="SCAN QR CODE", width=30,font=("Ariel Bold",15),bg='blue', command=scan)
but3.place(x=100, y=160)
scanned = tk.Label(window, text="RESULT", width=30, font=("Ariel Bold", 15))
scanned.place(x=100, y=200)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342935/using-opencv-with-tkinter)

Comment: Yeh thankyou i got it.