# Tkinter and cv2 freezes when trying to resize window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, opencv

Hey I have gotten a simple tkinter window to display my webcam using OpenCv from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23553802/6688026), see code

However, when I try to resize the window using my mouse curser, does the window go black and gets unresponsive.
How do I fix this, so I can resize the window after I have started the application?

**Update**

After a comment from @jizhihaoSAMA have I discovered that this bug is only affecting my mac running macOS 10.15.4 and python 3.7. However, it does not affect my windows 10 PC running python 3.7.

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

width, height = 800, 600
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack()


def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)


show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you need another thread.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that? 
(I have never worked with threads before so an example would be nice) 
@furcifer

Comment: In my computer,it won't happen when I resize the window.